# move multiple files depending on file name to a unique folder based on the filenames

Tags: batch-file, filenames

as the title i'm trying to figure out how to move multiple files depending on file name to a unique folder based on the filenames

for example lets say i have a folder with images from my houses webcam with such names like:

```
garden.bench.2013.image535.other.random.stuff.jpg
kids.swing.2013.image757.other.random.stuff.jpg
garage.2013.image563.other.random.stuff.jpg
front.garden.2013.image456.other.random.stuff.jpg
other.random.names.2013.image576.other.random.stuff.jpg
```

and i wanted to move JUST the 'garden bench', 'front garden' and 'garage' images to a specific folder (lets say C:\webcam\images) BASED on the files names from the bit before the date like this:

```
C:\webcam\images\Garden Bench\garden.bench.2013.image535.other.random.stuff.jpg
C:\webcam\images\Front Garden\front.garden.2013.image456.other.random.stuff.jpg
C:\webcam\images\Garage\garage.2013.image563.other.random.stuff.jpg
```

hope i'm explaining this ok and that this is doable and possible in 1 line

edit: atm i'm using code that looks like this:

```
move /Y garden.bench*.jpg "C:\webcam\images\Garden Bench\"
move /Y front.garden*.jpg "C:\webcam\images\Front Garden\"
move /Y garage*.jpg "C:\webcam\images\Garage\"
```

this is working fine but is very messy when you have 20 line that all look like that and would like a neater 1 line way of doing it

Comment: Messy or not it is an effective method of sorting your files - unless you have not given the real filenames.  They do not follow a common format like `name1.name2.restofname` so a simple command isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

:nextParam
   set selector=%~1
   if not defined selector goto :EOF
   for %%f in (%selector: =.%.%date:-4%.*.jpg) do (
      move /Y %%f "C:\webcam\images\%selector%\"
   )
   shift
goto nextParam
```

If previous Batch file is called moveFiles.bat, then the "1 line" way to move your files is this:

```
moveFiles "Garden Bench" "Front Garden" Garage
```